# Can foursquare users tag or otherwise categorize checkins?

Tags: foursquare, checkin

A client is proposing an app that would display checkins from users who have agreed to share their foursquare info with us; the catch is that they would want to distinguish between checkins that are and aren't relevant to this app. Is there a way to handle that, for instance with user comments at the time of checkin?

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the category of the venue the user has checked into, which should be available from the [check-in response](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin), or filter by specific venues directly. You can also filtering by content in a check-in shout is also a viable idea; [the #mom app](http://hashtagmom.com/) does this.